# dbGetQuery select all existing columns

Tags: mysql, sql, r, dplyr

I have a vector of columns that I would like to select from the databases. If the column is missing, I want to select all of the columns that exists. But, I am not sure how to specify this in my query?

For example, to select column `drat` I specify `"SELECT drat FROM mtcars"`. Let's say my column names are `drat` and `colMissing`.

My query does not work `"SELECT drat, colMissing FROM mtcars"` as `Error: no such column: colMissing` .

However, I want `drat` exporting. How can I make sure that all existing columns will be exported, and non existing skipped? In my real data, I have a long vector of columns names and many databases, so I want to do it automatically.

Dummy example:

```
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars") # select all columns
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT drat, wt, disp, colMissing FROM mtcars", n = 6)  # does not work as contains non existing columns name. How to export only existing ones?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SQL gives you an easy way to dynamically set the columns to select in this fashion. I think the easiest way to do this type of filtering is to determine the columns to join dynamically and create the query programmatically.

```r
cols <- c("drat", "wt", "disp", "colMissing")
cols_to_select <- intersect(dbListFields(con, "mtcars"), cols)
cols_to_select
# [1] "disp" "drat" "wt"  
qry <- paste("select", paste(dbQuoteIdentifier(con, cols_to_select), collapse = ","), "from mtcars")
qry
# [1] "select `disp`,`drat`,`wt` from mtcars"

head(dbGetQuery(con, qry))
#   disp drat    wt
# 1  160 3.90 2.620
# 2  160 3.90 2.875
# 3  108 3.85 2.320
# 4  258 3.08 3.215
# 5  360 3.15 3.440
# 6  225 2.76 3.460
```

I'm taking deliberate steps here to mitigate the risk of inadvertent SQL-injection that comes with `paste`-ing a query together. It *is* feasible that column names of an existing frame could be rather stupidly-malicious. (And no, I don't think the risk of these names is real, this type of mistake is much more likely to create a syntax error.)

```r
someframe <- data.frame(a=1,b=2)
names(someframe)[1] <- "Robert');DROP TABLE Students;--"
qry <- paste("select", paste(names(someframe), collapse = ","), "from mtcars")
qry
# [1] "select Robert');DROP TABLE Students;--,b from mtcars"
```

Okay, so that won't work here (despite https://xkcd.com/327/), but ... be careful when forming a query dynamically. `dbQuoteIdentifier` is one function with the intent of mitigating this risk. With comparison data (e.g., `WHERE cyl > 5`), it is much better to use [parameter-binding](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely#parameterized-queries) (i.e., `WHERE cyl > ?`); this doesn't work in the `SELECT` portion, however, so caveat emptor.

---

As an aside ... I believe SQL-injection discussions normally focus on the parameters (within the `WHERE` clause) of the query, not on the fields to be selected. However, it is *feasible* to make this happen with field names, though it requires knowing the target table name in the injection. (I'm using SQL Server below.)

```r
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "#r2mt", mtcars[1:2,])
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from #r2mt")
#       row_names mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1     Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
names(someframe)[1] <- 'cyl" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--'
qry <- paste("select", paste(dQuote(names(someframe)), collapse = ", "), "from #r2mt")
qry
# [1] "select \"cyl\" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--\", \"b\" from #r2mt"

DBI::dbGetQuery(con, qry)
#   cyl
# 1   6
# 2   6
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from #r2mt")
# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#r2mt'.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
# <SQL> 'select * from #r2mt'
```

I should note that while `dQuote` did not protect against this, `dbQuoteIdentifer` *did*:

```r
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "#r2mt", mtcars[1:2,])
qry <- paste("select", paste(DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, names(someframe)), collapse = ", "), "from #r2mt")
qry
# [1] "select \"cyl\"\" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--\", \"b\" from #r2mt"

DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from #r2mt")
#       row_names mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1     Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, qry)
# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'cyl" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--'.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'b'.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
# <SQL> 'select "cyl"" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--", "b" from #r2mt'
```

Where the clear difference in `qry` is shown here:

```r
# [1] "select \"cyl\" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--\", \"b\" from #r2mt"
# [1] "select \"cyl\"\" from #r2mt;DROP TABLE #r2mt;--\", \"b\" from #r2mt"
```

I was unable to defeat `dbQuoteIdentifier` in order to stop the escaping of `"` in this use.